# How to Show Product image in Opencart (order Invoice)?

Tags: php, html, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I want to show the Product image in the Invoice for Opencart, when user purchase something the invoice is generated with the product name only, i want the invoice to have the product image alaso, can you please let me know how i can do this ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://isenselabs.com/posts/how-to-add-store-logo-and-product-images-to-invoices-in-opencart-2x

Answer (score 0):

first load image this model like this 
`$this->load->model('tool/upload');` 
near line 512 before 
`$data['products'] = array();
foreach ($order_product_query->rows as $product) {`

Just make a function in your catlog/model/checkout/order to fetch image. pass product id as parameter and return that single variable.

call that function in $data such as 
`'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($this->myfunc($product['product_id']), $thumb_width, $thumb_height),`

Finally,

get your product image called in view file by image variable.